# Brand New HP Color LaserJet M452dn will not print out of box

Tags: windows-7, printer, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

I have a brand new Color LaserJet M452dn and I just plugged it in. Gave it a manual IP address. I can get to the homepage for the printer on the address. I can add the printer by IP address but when I go to print a test page it will not print anything. It will not print from notepad on a Windows 7 64 bit computer nor the test page. It will not print from an IP and WSD port connected Server 2008 R2 system.

I ran the HP Print & Scan Doctor and it printed the Internal test page but not the normal test page or anything at all. I have used the driver from the supplied CD as well as the newest PCL 6 driver on the website. V8.10.1320.2893

Is this printer broken or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Install the Full drivers package...http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=7527721&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4063

Comment: @Moab I have done that and still nothing.

Comment: Can any other PC print to it?

Comment: @Moab No. I added it to 2 separate computers over the network by IP and they cannot print.

Comment: make a post on this forum, there are some HP printer experts there...http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/bd-p/Install

Comment: As it is a brand new printer, I would call HP and get them to fix or replace it.

Comment: @Moab I already put a thread in and they told me to update drivers. Wasn't really helpful.

Comment: @hdhondt I think I am going to have to call them.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible to print from Windows 2008 and TCP/IP. I did a lot of research and nothing worked (HP M452nw). Even the newest drivers seem to not support 2008 (R1 here).

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Saying something isn't possible can be the right answer, but that, alone, leaves the reader with a question of whether you're correct or just aren't familiar with a  solution. This kind of answer is always better if you can cite a source.